# Array to DB insert PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a check box which takes some values and the below one is the post value which I get from my matrix form. Now the array value which I have below should be formated as like this

Post values:

```
Array (
    [31_1] => on
    [31_2] => on
    [31_3] => on
    [56_2] => on
    [56_4] => on
    [66_1] => on
    [66_3] => on
)
```

Expected value:

```
31=>1,2,3

56=>2,4

66=>1,3
```

I will be happy if I am able to store the values in a database table (`author_book`) like this:

```
  S.No      Author_ID       Book_IDs
  1         31              1,2,3
  2         56              2,4
  3         66              1,3
```

In short, the post values should be stored in DB tables for me to proceed further. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code would construct the queries for you, remember to use some data injection prevention mechanism

```
<?php

$x = array (
"31_1" => "on",
"31_2" => "on",
"31_3" => "on",
"56_2" => "on",
"56_4" => "on",
"66_1" => "on",
"66_3" => "on"
);

$newarray = array();

foreach($x as $key => $val){
$key = explode("_", $key);
$newkey = $key[0];
$newval = $key[1];
$newarray[$newkey][] = $newval;
}

foreach($newarray as $key => $val){
$query = "INSERT INTO (Author_ID, Book_IDs) VALUES (" . $key . ",'" . join(',', $val) . "')";
echo $query . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array_name as $key=> $value)
{

$var1=$key;
$var2=$value;

// here you can have your db statements to insert the values


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. There might be a shorter way of doing it too:

```
<?php
$array = array (
    '31_1' => 'on',
    '31_2' => 'on',
    '31_3' => 'on',
    '56_2' => 'on',
    '56_4' => 'on',
    '66_1' => 'on',
    '66_3' => 'on',
);

$new_array = array();

foreach($array as $ind=>$val){

    //breaks string at '_' and gets 31 and 1 separately
    $key_val = explode('_',$ind); 

    if(array_key_exists($key_val[0],$new_array)){
            //this is to append if key exists, eg. 31 => 1,2,3
        $new_array[$key_val[0]] = $new_array[$key_val[0]].",".$key_val[1]; 
    }
    else
    {
        $val = $key_val[1];
        $new_array[$key_val[0]] = $val;
    }
}

print_r($new_array);
?>
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/105513)**

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only wanted to insert values for author_id whose is set to ON
unset all the index set to OFF

Try something similar:

```
$books=array();
foreach($array_name as $key=> $value){
    if($value==='on'){
        //prepare the array
        list($author_id,$books[$author_id][])=explode("_",$key)
    }
}

foreach($temp as $k=>$v){        
    $q->query("INSERT INTO author_book(author_id,books_id) VALUES($k,".implode(',',$v)));
}
```

Thanks
and keep asking questions :)